# How to drag a sprite within limited circular area using andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have stone sprite class in which I have defined touch, drag and throw actions. My stone sprite move well when I touch and drag it around screen. My expectation is sprite should move only within limited circular area (visible/invisible).
This is my code below

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY)
{
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove() || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown() || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionOutside())
    {

        this.setX(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2);
        this.setY(pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);

    }
    else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
    {
        mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX((originX - getX()) * 5);
        mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY((originY - getY()) * 5);
        mPhysicsHandler.setAccelerationY(100);  
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027400/android-andengine-drag-and-drop-stacked-sprites

Comment: this does not solve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying the move when dragging, check to see if the touch event falls within the circle. To do this, measure the distance from the center of the circle. If the distance is less than the radius of the circle, then move the object. If not, do nothing.
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY)
{
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove() || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown() ||

```
pSceneTouchEvent.isActionOutside())
    {
        // Use Pythagorean theorem to get distance between 2 points;
        // center is a point you declare
        // radius is a value you declare that is the radius of the circular area
        Float distance = (pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - center.x)*(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - center.x) + (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - center.y) * (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - center.y);
        distance = Math.sqr(distance);
        if(distance < radius){
             // Only move if touch event is inside the circle area    
             this.setX(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2);
             this.setY(pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
        }

    }
    else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
    {
        mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX((originX - getX()) * 5);
        mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY((originY - getY()) * 5);
        mPhysicsHandler.setAccelerationY(100);  
    }
    return true;
}
```